# How to give a button (class) active hover-status on document ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On a website I have 4 clickable buttons (service buttons) on the homepage. They all respond individually to a css hover effect (background-color change) when the user hovers over one of the buttons. So far so god, this is what i want.

CSS:

```
.service-button:hover {
        background: #F7AA06;
        color: #1F213F;
}
```

The FIRST of the four buttons is the most important service. Therefore I want to highlight this button by having it "active" with the hover effect (background-color) when a user first enters the page. If the user hovers over one of the other buttons, the first button should "lose" it's hover-status and return to standard bg-color (white).

My temporary solution so far is to give the first button it's highlighted color with the nth:first-child selector from css. This kind a works as it sets the correct background-color to the first button. The problem is that the button does not change back to standard color if users hovers over on of the other buttons.

Is it possible to accomplish this from just css, or do I need to use jQuery?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bonzw.jpg

---

NEW fix! I actually got it working with some jQuery. Guess it's not the cleanest solution, but it does the job! Could/should it be resolved in a better way..?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// Add hover class to first button
$('.service-button.totalentreprise').addClass('bg-orange');

$('.service-button').hover(
  function() {
    // Remove hover class from first button
    $('.service-button.totalentreprise').removeClass('bg-orange');
    // Add hover class to any button
    $( this ).addClass('bg-orange');
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass('bg-orange');
  }
);

});
```

Comment: If you could share your code, it would be helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your code with us. But, yes it's best to use jQuery. Create a function so that when you hover over any of the other buttons it removes the highlighted class from the primary button.

Comment: Thanks, ingz! I did not include any code as it's not much to share. In the HTML I have the four service-buttons as a-links. And in the CSS I have the service-button:hover effect. I clearly miss the jQuery function to get this done, but need some help getting started. Yes, I'm new to jQuery ...

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

        $(".service-button").hover(function(e) { 
            $(this).css("background-color",e.type === "mouseenter"?"#F7AA06":"transparent") 
        });
})
```